# AES em PHP é seguro?

Tags: php, aes

Estou pretendendo implementar AES em uma área de uma intranet que está em desenvolvimento com a finalidade de que o usuário possa guardar dados importantes como senhas de contas e senhas de acesso a servidores, além de transferência de dados através de uma API para servidores externos, porém estou preocupado com a segurança pois estou utilizando uma classe já pronta: [Link](http://www.nacaolivre.com.br/php/criptografia-aes-em-objeto-php/).

Poderiam me tirar a dúvida se esta classe é segura o suficiente para este tipo de implementação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não. De um modo geral, somente é seguro utilizar bibliotecas que tenham passado por bastante escrutínio de especialistas nessa área. Não só a implementação precisa ser correta, mas ela precisa levar em conta coisas como [*side-channel attacks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack) (i.e. ataques que exploram falhas na **implementação** do algoritmo, não na sua lógica). Isso é algo que desenvolvedores "comuns" não estão qualificados a avaliar.

Entretanto, nesse caso nem é preciso ir tão longe: uma passada de olho no código-fonte revelou que ele opera segundo o [modo de operação ECB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_de_opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28criptografia%29#Modo_ECB_.28Electronic_CodeBook.29):

```
public function encrypt($text)
{
    $t = ""; // 16-byte bloco
    $y = ""; // Para retorno do bloco cifrado.


    $xsize = strlen($text);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $xsize; $i += 16){
        for ($j = 0; $j < 16; $j++){
            if (($i+$j) < $xsize){
                $t[$j] = $text[$i+$j];
            }else{
                $t[$j] = chr(0);
            }
        }

        $y .= $this->encryptBlock($t);
    }

    return $y;
}
```

O ECB é uma implementação "ingênua" da criptografia, o modo que uma pessoa que só estudou seu básico a implementaria. E é totalmente insegura. A imagem abaixo foi criptografada usando ECB, você consegue adivinhar do que ela se trata?

[image: ECB]

Quanto a uma alternativa segura, infelizmente conheço pouco de PHP para indicar algo. As funções [`mcrypt_generic`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mcrypt-generic.php) e [`mdecrypt_generic`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mdecrypt-generic.php) devem ser boas o bastante, mas não sei como usá-las corretamente. [Essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30166085/520779) também dá algumas sugestões que à primeira vista parecem boas (mas de novo, não sei avaliar). E se você tiver acesso ao [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.openssl.php), *talvez* exista alguma opção de criptografia AES que você possa usar (embora o foco dessa biblioteca seja criptografia de chave pública).

Seja qual solução você escolha, lembre-se de escolher um modo de operação seguro e, de preferência, [autenticado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) (ex.: CCM, GCM, EAX ou OCB). AES é só uma primitiva criptográfica, não um protocolo completo, é preciso ter isso em mente.

Comment: +1 pela resposta