# Como criptografar e descriptografar dados em PHP com segurança?

Tags: php, criptografia

Preciso gravar dados sigilosos no banco de dados, mas que possam ser lidos posteriormente (descriptografar).

Comment: Onde você pretende guardar a chave/senha? Essa criptografia/descriptografia ocorreria no lado do servidor, e não do cliente, certo? E seria a mesma para todo usuário, ou cada usuário teria sua própria senha? Por favor dê mais detalhes do seu cenário, do contrário fica difícil sugerir alguma coisa. Também é bom especificar *do que* exatamente você quer proteger esses dados (i.e. em que tipo de situação um atacante teria acesso ao BD mas não ao resto do servidor). Sugiro [edit] sua pergunta com mais informações, do contrário alguém vai responder "use AES" ou algo assim, o que não é muito útil...

Comment: O que pretendo armazenar são "dados gerais" e não senhas. Pois aprendi que para senhas não é necessário a decriptografia. Local: vou armazenar no banco (lado server somente) e todos registros podem ter a mesma chave de segurança.

Comment: Ok, mas como você vai fazer para que um eventual atacante que consiga acesso ao seu banco também não consiga acesso a essa chave?

Comment: Putz, dai não sei. Então não rola ter criptografia com decriptografia?

Comment: Sem resolver esse problema da chave, não, pelo menos não sem custos. Conheço duas alternativas, somente: 1) guarda a chave num arquivo de configuração, e usa pra cifrar alguns dados no banco; se o atacante só tiver acesso ao banco (via SQL Injection ou um backup achado no lixo) ele não consegue ler os dados. É uma situação limitada, mas funciona. 2) toda vez que você der o boot no servidor, você entra com a senha manualmente, e ela persiste somente em memória. Trabalhoso, e não sei como funcionaria em PHP, mas assim pelo menos nenhuma cópia do servidor revelaria os dados.

Comment: mesmo usando instancias diferentes, uma só pro BD e uma só pro PHP, ainda não rola ter uma criptografia ? é que queria pelo menos saber quais funções usar e como usar.

Comment: Então, você pode usar em alguns cenários limitados (tipo, se você acha que uma instância pode ser atacada e a outra não, então guardar a chave em uma e o BD na outra protege), não estou dizendo que é 100% inútil. Só é preciso ter cuidado pra não ter uma ilusão de segurança onde ela não existe. Quando a quais funções usar, não tenho experiência com PHP, mas à primeira vista o `mcrypt_generic` usando AES e CBC ou CTR (ECB nunca!) - ou melhor ainda, CCM, se suportado - deve ser bom o bastante. Veja [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78456/215) e minha resposta para mais detalhes.

Comment: Cada usuario tera uma chave para descriptografar suas mensagens ou seria apenas uma chave unica (do sistema)?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar duas funções no php uma para criptografar e outra para descriptografar e você salvaria no banco apensar essas strings(cuidado que elas podem ficar muito grandes), segue um exemplo das funções:

```
    <?php
    public static function getMacAlgoBlockSize($algorithm = 'sha1')
    {
        switch($algorithm)
        {
            case 'sha1':
            {
                return 160;
            }
            default:
            {
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

/**
* O metodo responsavel por descriptograr uma mensagem
* @param string $message Mensagem criptografada
* @param string $key Chave para realizar a descriptografia precisa ser a mesma usada na criptografia Exemplo: "skjj400ndkdçg00"
* @param string $mac_algorithm Tipo da descriptografia que sera usada Exemplo: md5 e sha1
*/
    public static function decrypt($message, $key, $mac_algorithm = 'sha1',
                                       $enc_algorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $enc_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)
    {
        $message= base64_decode($message);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($enc_algorithm, $enc_mode);
        $iv_dec = substr($message, 0, $iv_size);
        $message= substr($message, $iv_size);
        $message= mcrypt_decrypt($enc_algorithm, $key, $message, $enc_mode, $iv_dec);
        $mac_block_size = ceil(static::getMacAlgoBlockSize($mac_algorithm)/8);
        $mac_dec = substr($message, 0, $mac_block_size);
        $message= substr($message, $mac_block_size);

        $mac = hash_hmac($mac_algorithm, $message, $key, true);

        if($mac_dec == $mac)
        {
            return $password;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

/**
* O metodo responsavel por criptofrafar uma mensagem
* @param string $message Mensagem a ser criptograda
* @param string $key Chave para realizar a criptografia Exemplo: "skjj400ndkdçg00"
* @param string $mac_algorithm Tipo da criptograda que sera usada Exemplo: md5 e sha1
*/
    public static function encrypt($message, $key, $mac_algorithm = 'sha1',
                                       $enc_algorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $enc_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)
    {
        $mac = hash_hmac($mac_algorithm, $message, $key, true);
        $mac = substr($mac, 0, ceil(static::getMacAlgoBlockSize($mac_algorithm)/8));
        $message= $mac . $message;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($enc_algorithm, $enc_mode);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt($enc_algorithm, $key,
                                     $message, $enc_mode, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext);
    }
```

Acrescentei alguns comentarios para facilitar, mas os três métodos foram feito por:
[Métodos descritos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Approaches_to_Authenticated_Encryption)